# Draw trees or graph using python from a relationship table

Tags: python, graph, tree

Is there a way to draw a tree structure or graph using python from some relationship(parent/child) table?  The child may have more than one parent. For example,

```
|Parent  |Child
|none    |node 1
|none    |node 2
|node 1  |node 3
|node 2  |node 3
|node 2  |node 4
```

This gives

```
  node1    node2
     \      / \
      node3    node4
```

Comment: You could use turtle https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html and learn how to draw in different directions following some logic

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.  
StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.

Answer (score 0):

Coming from other languages that have trees builtin, python may seem a bit strange because it doesn't have one.

I would recommend building a parent to child dict, in which the values are actually lists of children:

`{node1:[node3], node2:[node3, node4]}`